# How to switch the rows in a random matrix?

Tags: matrices

I have an M by N matrix $A$. Does anyone know an easy way to find a N by N matrix $B$ such that $A*B = C$, where $C$ is the result of M by N matrix when switching the first and last row in $A$. Note: $M!=N$.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to change rows if you right-multiply by a matrix. So you need an $M\times M$ matrix $B$ to left-multiply by.

Take the identity matrix; then move the first $1$ to the last row and the last $1$ to the first row. This is the matrix $B$ that you want.

For instance, if $M=5$,
$$B=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
0&0&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
1&0&0&0&0
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But your method is only valid for the case when $M = N$.

Comment: True, my former "solution" exchanges columns instead of rows.